# Traceback: AttributeError:addinfourl instance has no attribute '__exit__'

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from urllib import urlopen
with urlopen('https://www.python.org') as story:
    story_words = []
    for line in story:
        line_words = line.split()
        for words in line_words:
            story_words.append(word)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '__exit__'
```

I am not understanding what's wrong with the above code and how to resolve it?

System information : python 2.7 in ubuntu oracle virtual box.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

That error is caused by this line:

```
with urlopen('https://www.python.org') as story:
```

You can't use any random object in a `with...as` statement.

There are two ways to fix this:

**Solution 1:** Use `contextlib.closing`:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(urlopen('https://www.python.org')) as story:
    ...
```

**Solution 2:**  Don't use a `with...as` statement; instead assign the value to a variable:

```
story = urlopen('https://www.python.org')
...
```

---

### Why is this happening?

You can't use any random object in a `with ... as` statement.

Only those objects will work which have two magic methods: `__enter__` and `__exit__`  implemented on them. Collectively, these methods are called "context manager". An introductory tutorial about this can be found below.

The `AttributeError` was raised because there isn't any context manager implemented for `urlopen` (*i.e.* it doesn't have `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods defined for it).

This leaves you with two choices:

1. either don't use `with...as` statement.
2. or use [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) (thanks to [@vaultah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2301450/vaultah) who provided this solution in a comment below). It automatically implements context manager for any object, thereby allowing you to use `with...as` statement.

(Note: In Python 3, `urlopen` does have a context manager, and thus can be used in a `with...as` statement.)

---

### Tutorial: How to implement the context manager?

To make an object work in a `with...as` statement, you first need to implement the context manager for that object. In simpler terms, you need to define `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods for that object/class.

Do read [these docs on context managers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types).

Example:

```
>>> class Person(object):
        """To implement context manager, just create two methods 
           __enter__ and __exit__.
        """

        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

        def __enter__(self):
            # The value returned by this method is 
            # assigned to the variable after ``as``
            return self

        def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback ):
            # returns either True or False
            # Don't raise any exceptions in this method
            return True


>>> with Person("John Doe") as p:
        print p.name

>>> "John Doe" #success
```

Comment: [Another possible solution](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing). Would be great if you could explain the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in Python 2.7:

```
from urllib import urlopen
story = urlopen('https://www.python.org')
story_words = []
for line in story:
    line_words = line.split()
    for words in line_words:
        story_words.append(words)
```

Comment: OP: Why was this marked as the answer? [xyres's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30628142/257924) actually answers the question of why.